# Erro ao criar uma tabela com sequelize "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sequelize' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express.js, sequelize-js

***Estou com o seguinte erro ao tentar cria uma tabela:***

> const Usuario = app.db.sequelize.define('usuario', {
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sequelize' of undefined

**Minha estrutura de pastas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Meu arquivo de configuração ( server.js )***

```
module.exports = function(){
    var express = require("express");
    var consign = require("consign");
    var app = express();

    consign({ cwd: "app" }).include("routes").then("config/db.js").then("controller").then("model").into(app);



    return app;
}
```

***Meu db.js***

```
var sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = new sequelize("william", "root", "root", { host: "localhost", dialect: "mysql",  operatorsAliases: false });
module.exports = db;
```

***Meu index.js***

```
var app = require("./app/config/server")();

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Rodando na porta 3000");
});
```

***E minha model que está com problema***

```
module.exports = function(app){
    const Usuario = app.db.sequelize.define('usuario', {
        nome: Sequelize.STRING,
        endereco: Sequelize.STRING
    });
}
```

*Obs: Estou usando o 
     express: 4.16.2, 
     cosign: 0.1.6,
     mysql2: 1.5.1,
     sequelize: 4.32.3*

Comment: tente trocar a injecao do consign onde esta `then("config/db.js")` para `then("config")`

Comment: @LucasCosta ele entra em um loop infinito.

Comment: deixa o server.js na raiz e nao dentro da pasta config e troque o caminho usado no index.js

Comment: @LucasCosta infelizmente o erro persiste o mesmo.

Comment: No seu db.js, tenta colocar module.exports = {db: db}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que achei aonde está o seu problema, eu também sofri muito quando ia utilizar o Sequelize e não o mongoose, seu erro está no arquivo `db.js`, ali vc precisa importar 2 instâncias do sequelize quando eu configuro o sequelize eu faço da seguinte maneira, vou utilizar os dados que você colocou na pergunta para ficar mais claro para você.

## Possível solução:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    database: 'willian',
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorAliases: false
})

module.exports = {
    Sequelize: Sequelize,
    sequelize: sequelize
}
```

> Perceba que existem 2 tipos de chamadas do Sequelize ele em maiúsculo e em minúsculo

#### E no model você pode declarar da seguinte maneira:

```
const db = require('../config/db')   //path de onde salvou seu db.js

const User= db.sequelize.define('users', {
    name: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    years: {
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    birthday: {
        type: db.Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
})

module.exports = User
```

> Não se esqueça de dar um `({force: true})` para criar a tabela

qualquer dúvida comente por favor, espero te-lo ajudado!